# Change method call font color Pycharm

Tags: pycharm

I would like to change font color for methods call. For instance `string.lower()` or `string.strip()`. I would like to change the color of `lower()` or `strip()` in PyCharm. I have tweaked around quite some time and I can't find where to change it. I did change other code font color but can't find specifically for methods call. Does anyone know how to do this in PyCharm?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you **can't** highlight function calls in PyCharm **yet**.

See [How-to-syntax-highlight-Python-function-calls](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206601025-How-to-syntax-highlight-Python-function-calls-?sort_by=votes)

It's unfortunate they didn't implement such a basic feature in their font color editor. The post above is from 2014 (3 years ago at the time I'm writing these lines...)

Comment: Well... despite the feature not being there, PyCharm is a great editor. I start using vscode for most of my development and have a great python extension. I'm impressed with Microsoft on how they have put together such text editor. Nowadays the web is the platform for most development applications, and their intellisense for JS out of the box is awesome.

Comment: I agree on pretty much everything you said. I started to do Python on VS Code months ago but switched recently to PyCharm because I found their debugger/task runner a little bit weak where JetBrain's one is pretty powerful and can be used out the box without any tweak or special conf.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean function call. You can change it: Settings -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> Language Defaults -> Identifiers -> "Function Call".

[Function_call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ww6ob.png)